What is the correct syntax with orderby for this OData expression used for Azure.Data.Tables in C#?
I searched likely everywhere, but don't find a right page of where somebody can explain me how write the right syntax for orderby.
I think there are problems with this ampersand, it's a query-operator and I'm using it inside the filter condition.
Everything works fine when I don't use orderby and top.
using Azure.Data.Tables;

// ...
TableClient releases_table;

// ...
releases_table = tableServiceClient.GetTableClient(tableName: "releases");

// ...
string filter = $"PartitionKey eq '{results[0]["productType"]}' and RowKey ne '' and RowKey ge '{startDate:yyyyMMddHHmmss}' and RowKey le '{endDate:yyyyMMddHHmmss}'&$orderby=Timestamp desc&$top=1";

var queryResponse2 = releases_table.Query<TableEntity>(filter: filter);

I want the newest entry in my Azure Table based on the Timestamp property.


What is the correct syntax with orderby for this OData expression used for Azure.Data.Tables in C#?

The below code uses correct syntax with orderby and works fine with OrderByDescending property as you can see in the below code. It sorts the Price column in descending order as shown in the output below.
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "*****";
        string tableName = "TableA";

        TableServiceClient serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(connectionString);
        TableClient tableClient = serviceClient.GetTableClient(tableName);

        string filter = $"PartitionKey eq 'Products'";

        List<TableEntity> results = await FetchSortedResults(tableClient, filter, "Price");

        foreach (TableEntity entity in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {entity.GetString("Name")}, Price: {entity.GetDouble("Price")}");
        }
    }

    static async Task<List<TableEntity>> FetchSortedResults(TableClient tableClient, string filter, string orderByProperty)
    {
        List<TableEntity> entities = new List<TableEntity>();

        await foreach (TableEntity entity in tableClient.QueryAsync<TableEntity>(filter))
        {
            entities.Add(entity);
        }

        entities = entities.OrderByDescending(e => e.GetDouble(orderByProperty)).ToList();

        return entities;
    }
}

In the above code the OrderByDescending property has used with correct syntax and below is the output where the data retrieved successfully.
Output:

For more information, refer to this document.

Great to know it helped :)
